# Angular js - cannot find scope data defined in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Con you please tell how to call the view page after all the operations done in the controller. Currently i am facing issues as in javascript, i am assigning a variable which will come after calling a service from controller and the data from services will come after some time.

Comment: Could you give us more information.. for example code??

Comment: Like say i want to pass my current lat long to get map information.

Answer (score 0):

From this controller i want to fetch map 
information from my lat long after certain interval of time but in the view page i am getting the map information but after fraction of seconds so i am facing problem in the google map as the variable which i defined in view page is undefined for fraction of second. I tried by setting the value in a hidden variable and getting the data but the variable defined in script is undefined.

```
frontApp.controller('mapController', function ($scope, $rootScope, services, $location, $window, $interval) {

    is_login(1);
    update();

    function update() {

        if (navigator.geolocation) {


            $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {

                    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;


                    services.getMapData(latitude, longitude).then(function (data) {

                        $scope.mapdata = data.data;

                });
            });

        }
        else
        {
            window.location.href = site_url + "#/dashboard";
        }
    }

    $interval(update, 1000);
});
```

Comment: you should edit your original question with this new information

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert so i'm sure someone with more experience will chime in. I'm pretty sure you need to initialize the module correctly. Your example doesn't appear have any dependencies defined (i.e. $scope, $location...etc).

```
//you also need the app as well inorder to attach the controller to.

var frontApp = angular.module('mappingModule', []);

frontApp.controller('mapController',['$scope', '$rootscope','$location','$window', '$interval', function ($scope, $rootScope, services, $location, $window, $interval) {

// do things with your data here.
// i'm going to out on a limb and say you probably need to make sure you have a popup that 
// that prompts to user to share their location or navigator wont give it to you
}]);
```

Also if you want the module to run you need to link onto the page. More of your code and setup is needed to provide a better answer.

You also need to define Services. uh, I believe it's called a Factory that takes care of that which needs to be referenced in a dependency in the controller dependencies array. Seeing your services code would help.

Overall it sounds like you aren't passing the location data to the controller.